# Nao consigo conectar pagina jsp ao banco Oracle

Tags: jsp, oracle11g

> Esse meu projeto  Web Funcionava na escola, mas no meu pc nao vai..
>   Era pra retornar "conectado no  banco  oracle" e retorna
>   "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver "
>
> Codigo classe conexão:

```
package classeConexao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class Conexao 
{
    private String URL     = "";   
    private String DRIVER  = "";
    private String USUARIO = "";
    private String SENHA   = "";
    private String BANCO   = "ORACLE";

    public void SelectBD(String Banco)
    {
        BANCO = Banco;
        if (BANCO.equals("SQL"))
        {   
            //CONEXAO SQL EXPRESS 
            URL     = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/BancoSQL;";
            DRIVER  = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            USUARIO = "sa";
            SENHA   = "123456";
        }
        else if(BANCO.equals("ORACLE"))
        {
            //CONEXAO ORACLE EXPRESS
            URL     = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            DRIVER  = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            USUARIO = "android"; //"sys as sysdba";
            SENHA   = "123456";
        }
    }

    public Statement ponte;
    public String status = "";
    public String getStatus() 
    {
        return status;
    }

        public Conexao()
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Banco "+ BANCO);
            SelectBD(BANCO);
            if (BANCO.equals("SQL"))
            {   
                Class.forName(DRIVER);
                Connection con;
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USUARIO,SENHA);
                ponte = con.createStatement();
            }
            else if(BANCO.equals("ORACLE"))
            {
                Class.forName(DRIVER);
                Connection con;
                OracleDataSource ds;
                ds = new OracleDataSource();
                ds.setURL(URL);
                con = ds.getConnection(USUARIO,SENHA);
                ponte = con.createStatement();
            }
            status = "Conectado no banco " + BANCO + "!!!" ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void manutencao(String sql)
    {
        try {
            ponte.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

> Codigo  da pagina  jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="classeConexao.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AULA DE TEEM - Integrando soluções!</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>CADASTRO - Lista de Contatos</h2>
<hr>
<a href="listagem.jsp">Listagem dos Contatos</a>
<hr>
<%
Conexao conexao = new Conexao();

 out.println(conexao.getStatus());
%>
<hr>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

> Rodo ela com Tomcat v7.0 Referenciei ojdbc6, jtds-1.2.5 e classes12
>
> Obs.: outro projeto Java conectou normal ao banco

Comment: E tem alguma exceção no log?

Comment: Banco ORACLEjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at classeConexao.Conexao.<init>(Conexao.java:58)
 at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:78)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

Comment: at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)

Comment: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Os drivers jtds e ojdbc6 eram usados  no Eclipse  Luna, e não consegui criar pagina jsp nele. Por isso baixei outro. Não sei se tem a ver tbm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive o problema de novo com não reconhecimento, e coloquei o jtds e ojdbc6 diretamente na pasta lib do apache tomcat e removendo as referencias antigas para não ter duplicações de bibliotecas. E ao fazer tudo isso, salvei e reiniciei o eclipse. Desta vez funcionou com jdk 1.8 sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a exceção que você postou

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

a aplicação não está encontrando o driver jdbc do Oracle. Você pode fazer o download dele por esta página: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/survey/index.html

Veja a versão do seu banco e baixe o driver referente.

Se já tiver feito isso, então pode ser que o driver não esteja no build da sua ide. Se usa o eclipse, vá até a pasta lib pela arvore do projeto e clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o driver. Vai aparecer uma opção para incluir no build, clique nela.

Outra situação que poderia vir a resultar nesse erro é o conflito entre bibliotecas. Por exemplo, duas versões diferentes do driver, por exemplo, uma na aplicação e outra no tomcat. Dai o ideal é remover uma delas.

Comment: tentei  as tres opcoes e nada

Comment: Revisei sua postagem e vi que você citou isso "Rodo ela com Tomcat v7.0 Referenciei ojdbc6, jtds-1.2.5 e classes12". Remova essa biblioteca classes12, acho que é ela quem está causando o conflito. Ela era usada como dirver do oracle antes da versão 1.3 do Java.

Comment: minha jre1.8.0_144 e minha jdk1.8.0_144, será que a jdbc que tenho que  ter é a ojdbc8?

Comment: agora apareceu isso     "The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path"

Comment: junto desse ---------------------------------------------------------Banco ORACLE
java.sql.SQLException: URL Oracle Inválido especificado
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)

Comment: `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` aponta a falta da api de Servlet. Pode obte-la em https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0. Caso já tenha ela entre suas bibliotecas, então faltou adiciona-la no build da IDE, aquele processo que eu citei anteriormente que teria que fazer com o driver de conexão.

Comment: Sobre o erro do banco de dados, ao que parece a sua URL de acesso ao banco tem algum erro. Pelo menos é isso que a exceção está dizendo. Qual a versão do driver Oracle que está usando? Continua com a 6 ou trocou pela 8?

Comment: tentei tudo isso e configurei o Server TomCat novamente excluindo os outros..         E notei tambem que na hora de  criar o server na tinha um alerta que dizendo  que o project facets nao iria rodar com jre1.8. Mudei em properties do projeto - project facets - java - ai cliquei na setinha mudei de 1.8 para 1.7. Eu já tinha instalado jre1.7.. Funcionou. Valeu!!!